# ExtJs 6: how to directly get specific grid cell component by known position

Tags: grid, cell, extjs6

I have a simple grid and would like to manage some specific cell.

Here it is: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/32q1

I know its row number and column name.

But how I can directly get cpecific cell as a component?

I need to make setEnable and setStyle to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the `getCell` method from the `Ext.view.Table` (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getCell)

Your code could look like this:

```
    let grid = Ext.getCmp('mygrid'),
        column = grid.getView().getGridColumns()[1],
        record = grid.getStore().getAt(2),
        cell = grid.getView().getCell(record, column);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32s2) for it.

Comment: Notice that in Ext 6.7 [getCell](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getCell) uses third parameter to return data as a component!

Comment: Yes, that's even better! I just checked the method for your version so I didn't see this.